# Using a PeriodIndex to slice a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a few `pandas` `series` with `PeriodIndex` of varying frequency. I'd like to filter these based on another `PeriodIndex` of which the frequency is in principle unknown (specified directly in the example below as `selectionA` or `selectionB`, but in practice stripped from another `series`).

I've found 3 approaches, each with its own downside, shown in the example below. Is there a better way?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

y = pd.Series(np.random.random(4),  index=pd.period_range('2018', '2021', freq='A'), name='speed')
q = pd.Series(np.random.random(16), index=pd.period_range('2018Q1', '2021Q4', freq='Q'), name='speed')
m = pd.Series(np.random.random(48), index=pd.period_range('2018-01', '2021-12', freq='M'), name='speed')

selectionA = pd.period_range('2018Q3', '2020Q2', freq='Q') #subset of y, q, and m
selectionB = pd.period_range('2014Q3', '2015Q2', freq='Q') #not subset of y, q, and m

#Comparing some options: 
#1: filter method
#2: slicing
#3: selection based on boolean comparison

#1: problem when frequencies unequal: always returns empty series
yA_1 = y.filter(selectionA, axis=0) #Fail: empty series
qA_1 = q.filter(selectionA, axis=0) 
mA_1 = m.filter(selectionA, axis=0) #Fail: empty series
yB_1 = y.filter(selectionB, axis=0) 
qB_1 = q.filter(selectionB, axis=0) 
mB_1 = m.filter(selectionB, axis=0)

#2: problem when frequencies unequal: wrong selection and error instead of empty result
yA_2 = y[selectionA[0]:selectionA[-1]]  
qA_2 = q[selectionA[0]:selectionA[-1]] 
mA_2 = m[selectionA[0]:selectionA[-1]] #Fail: selects 22 months instead of 24
yB_2 = y[selectionB[0]:selectionB[-1]] #Fail: error
qB_2 = q[selectionB[0]:selectionB[-1]] 
mB_2 = m[selectionB[0]:selectionB[-1]] #Fail: error

#3: works, but very verbose
yA_3 =y[(y.index >= selectionA[0].start_time) & (y.index <= selectionA[-1].end_time)]
qA_3 =q[(q.index >= selectionA[0].start_time) & (q.index <= selectionA[-1].end_time)]
mA_3 =m[(m.index >= selectionA[0].start_time) & (m.index <= selectionA[-1].end_time)]
yB_3 =y[(y.index >= selectionB[0].start_time) & (y.index <= selectionB[-1].end_time)]
qB_3 =q[(q.index >= selectionB[0].start_time) & (q.index <= selectionB[-1].end_time)]
mB_3 =m[(m.index >= selectionB[0].start_time) & (m.index <= selectionB[-1].end_time)]
```

Many thanks

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html

Comment: That only seems to work for dataframes or series with a datetime index, not with a period index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by adding `start_time` and `end_time` to the slice range:

```
yA_2fixed = y[selectionA[0].start_time: selectionA[-1].end_time]
qA_2fixed = q[selectionA[0].start_time: selectionA[-1].end_time] 
mA_2fixed = m[selectionA[0].start_time: selectionA[-1].end_time] #now has 24 rows
yB_2fixed = y[selectionB[0].start_time: selectionB[-1].end_time] #doesn't fail; returns empty series
qB_2fixed = q[selectionB[0].start_time: selectionB[-1].end_time] 
mB_2fixed = m[selectionB[0].start_time: selectionB[-1].end_time] #doesn't fail; returns empty series
```

But if there's a more concise way to write this, I'm still all ears. I especially would like to know if it's possible to do this filtering in a way that is more 'native' to the `PeriodIndex`, i.e., not converting it into `datetime` instances first with the `start_time` and `end_time` attributes.

Comment: When you see that much repetition in code, you can always shorten it.  Assign variables to `aStart = selectionA[0].start_time` `aEnd=selectionA[0].end_time` also, with `bStart` and `bEnd`...  Then use `yA_2fixed = y[aStart:aEnd]` and etc...

Comment: Yes, or I could use `slA = slice(simulationA[0].start_time, selectionA[-1].end_time)` and then just `yA_2fixed = y[slA]`. I was more thinking about losing the `start_time` and `end_time`, as feels like a 'weak' solution that translates the problem into a timestamp/`datetime` comparison, instead of keeping the filter on a `Period`-basis native to the series. But maybe that is asking for a lot ;)